# How to use JOIN LIKE with AND Operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-like

Look at this scenario first:

I have table1 with column C1 and 2 records in it with values Text1 and Text2.

```
SELECT * FROM TabelX
INNER JOIN table1 ON TableX.Name LIKE '%'+table1.C1+'%'
```

This code means:

```
SELECT * FROM TabelX
WHERE TableX.Name LIKE '%Text1%' OR TableX.Name LIKE '%Text2%'
```

Now how can I change JOIN LIKE that means AND not OR? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TabelX
WHERE TableX.Name LIKE '%Text1%' AND TableX.Name LIKE '%Text2%'
```

Comment: I had asked the same question and got an answer from [@lc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/44853/lc). You may refer the below thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825906/like-clause-with-and-operator-in-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this can work for you:

```
BEGIN
declare @mycounter integer
select @mycounter = count (*) from table1

SELECT * FROM TabelX
where @mycounter = (select * from table1 where TableX.Name LIKE '%'+table1.C1+'%')
END
```