# 'LIKE' clause with 'AND' operator in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-like

I have exactly the same requirement as in this thread. [How to use JOIN LIKE with AND Operator in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745766/how-to-use-join-like-with-and-operator-in-sql-server)

I have been clueless despite searching the net for hours.

I have a table 'Filter' with column 'Value' and 2 records in it as 'Value1' and 'Value2' as varchar values.

```
Select * From MasterTable
Inner Join Filter ON MasterTable.Name LIKE '%' + Filter.Value + '%'
```

This query means:

```
Select * From MasterTable
Where MasterTable.Name LIKE '%Value1%' OR MasterTable.Name LIKE '%Value2%'
```

Now how can I change JOIN LIKE that means AND not OR? Something like:

```
Select * From MasterTable
Where MasterTable.Name LIKE '%Value1%' AND MasterTable.Name LIKE '%Value2%'
```

Can anyone show me a way out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generally rewrite a "X matches all Y" query as "X does not have any Y that do not match" - or in other words a `NOT EXISTS` query for the inverse of Y.

```
select *
from MasterTable
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Filter
    where MasterTable.Name not like '%' + Filter.Value + '%'
)
```